# Gitlab repository error failed to find pack entry

Tags: git, gitlab

Gitlab repository corrupted. getting 500 internal server error on frontend.

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-11 16:22:02 +0530
Processing by DashboardController#show as HTML
Read fragment views/projects/44-20160408141103000000000/dashboard/show/cc53ca8d7b83612d3f40df2a690c7950 (0.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 27ms

ActionView::Template::Error (Object not found - failed to find pack entry (509db335d2df02b878c18e1a6fe84393da6978c1)):
    2:   = link_to project_path(project), class: dom_class(project) do
    3:     - if avatar
    4:       .dash-project-avatar
    5:         = project_icon(project, alt: '', class: 'avatar project-avatar s40')
    6:     .dash-project-access-icon
    7:       = visibility_level_icon(project.visibility_level)
    8:     %span.str-truncated
  app/models/repository.rb:8:in `new'
```

Comment: Your question is not a question. Looks like spam. So, please, either edit it or remove it before it it's closed for moderators. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5):

Do the below steps

```
1. # cd gitlab/repositories/<namespace>/<reponame>.git 

2. # git fsck
If any error like below
error: object file objects/11/fbf0dfb1a54283e84044b5e99230efbafd77d8 is empty
error: object file objects/11/fbf0dfb1a54283e84044b5e99230efbafd77d8 is empty
fatal: loose object 11fbf0dfb1a54283e84044b5e99230efbafd77d8 (stored in objects/11/fbf0dfb1a54283e84044b5e99230efbafd77d8) is corrupt

3.  # find . –size 0 –delete  
This will delete all files which has 0 byte size and corrupt

4.  # git fsck
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (4970/4970), done.
error: HEAD: not a commit
error: refs/heads/master: not a commit
dangling commit de516dd3d99d13147b6e2f946fe5b8c0660e4eed

5.   Try to push code from local without add and commit 
# git push origin <branch>
If got below error
remote: error: Could not read 5329f756010fad47026f112dc7126bdaa2f9ad7f
remote: fatal: Failed to traverse parents of commit  8eecd866caa916a3b2e8550153f0bb5a54a28919
remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
fatal: protocol error: bad pack header

6.  Go to cd gitlab/repositories/<namespace>/<reponame>.git
# rm –fr ref/head/<branchname>
# git fsck
notice: HEAD points to an unborn branch (master)
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
notice: No default references
dangling commit eb84ebc9010ea3d3d5646b4eab1bacd358178fbd

7.  Try to push code from local without add and commit 
# git push origin <branch>

Done your code updated successfully !!!
```

Answer (score 1):

If you apply that in 2023, With Git 2.41 (Q2 2023), "[`git fsck`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a02675ad907a31205b2de86a945eec327de38132/Documentation/git-fsck.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck))</sup> learned to validate the on-disk pack reverse index files.

It can detect more pack entries.

See [commit 5a6072f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a6072f631dcf4d9f65e83b08d14c82e2af45dd8), [commit 5f658d1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5f658d1b577722111564f51962d6af33d1fe96c6), [commit d975fe1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d975fe1fa57d57cfd21a97f96f4a94b99f50f2f4), [commit 0d30fee](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0d30feef3c55f63f8db1dc1e52071090d16dfaaf) (17 Apr 2023) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
See [commit 3c63503](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3c63503759136836dee84ea28835b1b4ef8882bf) (17 Apr 2023) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a02675a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a02675ad907a31205b2de86a945eec327de38132), 27 Apr 2023)</sup>

> ### [`fsck`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0d30feef3c55f63f8db1dc1e52071090d16dfaaf): create scaffolding for rev-index checks
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> The '`fsck`' builtin checks many of Git's on-disk data structures, but does not currently validate the pack rev-index files (a `.rev` file to pair with a `.pack` and `.idx` file).
>
> Before doing a more-involved check process, create the scaffolding within [`builtin/fsck.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0d30feef3c55f63f8db1dc1e52071090d16dfaaf/builtin/fsck.c) to have a new error type and add that error type when the API method `verify_pack_revindex()` returns an error.
> That method does nothing currently, but we will add checks to it in later changes.
>
> For now, check that '[`git fsck`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0d30feef3c55f63f8db1dc1e52071090d16dfaaf/Documentation/git-fsck.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck))</sup> succeeds without any errors in the normal case.
> Future checks will be paired with tests that corrupt the `.rev` file appropriately.

Comment: See also [commit cd2b740](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cd2b740ca95291b81b8e75000d2ee76b4f735877)