# Unable to clone my git repo from Heroku

Tags: git, heroku, git-clone

We've been using Heroku to host our git repo for years.  I tried to clone our repo on a new machine w/ this command `heroku git:clone -aAPP_NAME` but am getting this error:

```
remote: error: Could not read XXXXXXXX
remote: fatal: Failed to traverse parents of commit YYYYYYYY
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: erro
fatal: protocol error: bad pack header
```

I checked locally for the missing commit and I have it so I'm wondering if there is a way for me to push the missing commit to Heroku?  And maybe check to see if the local commit I have is still valid?

I've also noticed this error on our CircleCI deploys but it doesn't seem to be causing any problems.

Comment: It seems like an `ssh` problem. Test the connectivity to the `git` remote with a test `ssh`

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the heroku server (maybe `heroku run bash`), try the process described in "[Gitlab repository corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36599198/6309)" (step 6 and 7 mainly)

It is essentially about soft deleting the remote branch, and pushing your local branch again (`git push heroku master`), provided your local repo is clean.

Comment: I tried logging into Heroku w/.bash, but the git repo isn't stored on the dyno, they have a separate repo.  I also tried deleting the master branch, but it wouldn't let me.  Is there a way to replace a commit by pushing it?

Comment: @Josh "a commit" not easily. But if you have a valid copy of the repo (one you can clone around without any error message), you can "`git push --force`" a branch to the remote repo.